# Open a div from top and bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2tBGE/209/

I just want to open a div with animation after a user clicked on a menu item.
For example, when clicking on the second item, clicked item and previous item should push to the top of the page and below item should push to the bottom of the page.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('ul li a').on('click', function(){
     $(this).parent().next().css({
      'display':'block'
      })
    })
});
```

```css
ul{
  list-style: none;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.js_item{
  display:none;  
}

li a{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover{
    background: #9c0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="main">
    <li><a href="#">main menu1</a></li>
    <div class="load_content_for_menu_1 js_item">1</div>
    <li><a href="#">main menu2</a></li>
    <div class="load_content_for_menu_2 js_item">2</div>

    <li><a href="#">main menu3</a></li>
     <div class="load_content_for_menu_3 js_item">3</div>
    <li><a href="#">main menu4</a></li>
    <div class="load_content_for_menu_4 js_item">4</div>
    <li><a href="#">main menu5</a></li>
    <div class="load_content_for_menu_5 js_item">5</div>

</ul>
```

Comment: And what did you tried? Please insert your [code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question

Comment: I share my code with you, but actually, I don't know how to open a div and slide down and up at the same time and make it full page

Comment: I think after click event target `div` should be at `top: 0` and with `height` set to eg. `100vh` and correct z-index.

Comment: thanks but I want to push above element to top and below element to bottom, with top:0 only clicked element will be at the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: I've made a small edit to your html structure so that each `.toggled_content` `<div>` is the child of each `<li>`.

---

With the following jQuery methods you can achieve this.

[slideToggle()](https://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)

> Display or hide the matched elements with a sliding motion.

[toggleClass()](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

> Add or remove one or more classes from each element in the set of matched elements, depending on either the class's presence or the value of the state argument.

[find()](https://api.jquery.com/find)

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

```js
var allContent = $("li");
allContent.find(".toggled_content").hide();

$(".toggler").on("click", function() {
  var $thisParent = $(this).parent();
  if (!$thisParent.hasClass('open')) {
    $thisParent
      .parent()
      .find(".open")
      .toggleClass("open")
      .find(".toggled_content")
      .slideToggle();
  }

  $thisParent
    .toggleClass("open")
    .find(".toggled_content")
    .slideToggle();
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  background: #9c0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="main">
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="toggler">main menu1</a>
    <div class="toggled_content">1</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="toggler">main menu2</a>
    <div class="toggled_content">2</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="toggler">main menu3</a>
    <div class="toggled_content">3</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="toggler">main menu4</a>
    <div class="toggled_content">4</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="toggler">main menu5</a>
    <div class="toggled_content">5</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

### Edit:

Or just use the [jquery-ui accordion widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/).

```js
$("#accordion").accordion({
  heightStyle: "fill",
  active: 3
});

$("#accordion").on("accordionactivate", function(event, ui) {
  const offset = ui.newHeader[0].offsetTop;
  $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
    scrollTop: offset
  }, 200);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.ui-accordion {
  height: 200vh; /* simulate height with content */
  background: #eee;
}
.ui-accordion-header {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.ui-accordion-header:hover {
  background: #9c0;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>main menu 1</h3>
  <div>1</div>
  <h3>main menu 2</h3>
  <div>2</div>
  <h3>main menu 3</h3>
  <div>3</div>
  <h3>main menu 4</h3>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's just an accordion, please look at the transition and full-screen menu on a gif

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you want from the gif you have uploaded because it is quite small, it plays quickly and it loops.

Comment: @Chino - After looking closely at the gif, using screenshots!, the clicked entry fills the entire viewport and the `li` elements immediately above/below are no longer visible. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Chino Is there anything else you need help with?

Comment: thanks for your help, can you collapse it smoothly like you expand it ?

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little more complex than it appears, because you probably do not want any of the DIVs to be made full-screen. Rather, you want the headings of all the DIVs to remain visible, and the contents of any one content div to fill all remaining vertical space.

jQueryUI does this for you, using their [accordion tabs](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/) widget. You can either include jQueryUI in your project and use their functionality, or you can examine their code and see how they did it, then modify their code to work in your own project.

To incorporate jQueryUI is simple: just add it the same way you would add jQuery, right after the call to jQuery *(that is, you also need jQuery for jQueryUI to work, and the link to jQueryUI must follow the link for jQuery)* See [this link](http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/getting-started/) for a code example.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: after click menu should be full-screen and content push element to top and bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding `.css()` I have added `.show()`. It basically does the same by adding `display:block`

Try adding blow

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('ul li a').on('click', function() {
    $('.js_item').hide('slow')
    $(this).parent().next().show('slow')

  })
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.js_item {
  display: none;
}

li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  background: #9c0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="main">
  <li><a href="#">main menu1</a></li>
  <div class="load_content_for_menu_1 js_item">1</div>
  <li><a href="#">main menu2</a></li>
  <div class="load_content_for_menu_2 js_item">2</div>

  <li><a href="#">main menu3</a></li>
  <div class="load_content_for_menu_3 js_item">3</div>
  <li><a href="#">main menu4</a></li>
  <div class="load_content_for_menu_4 js_item">4</div>
  <li><a href="#">main menu5</a></li>
  <div class="load_content_for_menu_5 js_item">5</div>

</ul>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: please look at the transition on the gif, that's what I want to create

Comment: Check again. I have edited the answer. You can achieve the same using above code

Comment: Sorry but it's not what I want, assume that user click on middle nav item, menu item on top of the element should be on top of the page and menu item on below should push to bottom

Comment: yea, kind of. BUT accordion push element only to top, not bottom

Comment: I have updated my answer. Hope this will give some hint to achieve expected.

Comment: Sorry, but I think you get me wrong, I don't think it's possible with show/hide